# Changing the style of numbers (of sections and chapters)

Tags: sectioning, chapters, classicthesis

I would like to change the style of numbers of sections and chapters. In particular I would like to use the style of Classic thesis. How can I do?

```
\documentclass[twoside,10pt,b5paper]{book}

\raggedbottom

\usepackage[dvips=false,pdftex=false,vtex=false]{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}

\usepackage[a4,center]{crop}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\geometry{%
   includeheadfoot,
   margin=1.8cm,
   bmargin=1.4cm
}

\usepackage{soul}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\usepackage{tikz,tikz-cd}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{textcomp, gensymb}

\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,mathrsfs}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}

\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{FrontBackmatter/Bibliography.bib}

\definecolor{indigo(dye)}{rgb}{0.0, 0.25, 0.42}
\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
        linkcolor = indigo(dye),
        filecolor=black,
        urlcolor  = black!40!cyan,
        citecolor = indigo(dye),
        anchorcolor = red!60!black]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linktocpage}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage[pagestyles, clearempty,explicit]{titlesec}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\usepackage{palatino,eulervm}

\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion]{microtype}

\usepackage{eqparbox}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind} %per il TOC

\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\chk#1{#1^{\smash{\scalebox{.7}[1.4]{\rotatebox{90} 
{\guilsinglleft}}}}}

\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}

\makeatletter               
\renewcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                \thispagestyle{empty}%
                \global\@topnum\z@
                \@afterindentfalse
                \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\section}[display]{\fontsize{10.8}{0} \bfseries}{}{0pt} 
{\colorbox{black!15!white}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax} 
{\textcolor{black}{\thesection\quad#1}}}}[]
\titlespacing*{\section}{-0.8cm}{0.4cm}{0.2cm}[0pt]

\newtcbox{\mybox}{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\small \leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\small \rightmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}


\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```

I would like the numbers to be like the ones in the image.[image]

Comment: handwritten sketch of the desired output

Comment: Please clarify (a) your current document setup and (b) what you mean by "style of numbers". E.g., do you mean oldstyle numerals instead of lining numerals, or do you want to farther and use the exact font used in `classicthesis` documents?

Comment: @Mico I modified my question.

Comment: Many thanks for posting some code. Please clarify whether the oldstyle numerals should be used everywhere in the document or just chapters and sectioning headers.

Comment: @Mico I think I'd like the numbers' style to be the same everywhere except in the text of the thesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is ist something like that you're after?  I had to change `palatino` to `newpx` , which uses TeX-Gyre Pagella (a Palatino clone) to use old-syle numbers in text, and to format \ chapter with `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass[twoside,10pt,b5paper, svgnames]{book}

\raggedbottom

\usepackage[dvips=false,pdftex=false,vtex=false]{geometry}
%\usepackage{changepage}

\geometry{%
   includeheadfoot,
   margin=1.8cm,
   bmargin=1.4cm
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage[pagestyles, clearempty,explicit]{titlesec}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage[osf]{newpxtext}
\usepackage{newpxmath}

\usepackage[protrusion=true, expansion]{microtype}

\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\bfseries\filright}{\huge\chaptername\enspace{\color{Gainsboro}\scalebox{2.5}{\thechapter}}}{4ex}{\Huge #1}

\titleformat{\section}[display]{\fontsize{10.8}{0} \bfseries}{}{0pt}
{\colorbox{black!15!white}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}
{\textcolor{black}{\thesection\quad#1}}}}[]
\titlespacing*{\section}{-0.8cm}{0.4cm}{0.2cm}[0pt]

\newtcbox{\mybox}{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\small \leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\small \rightmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{2}

\chapter{A chapter}

\section{A section}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]